# Using javascript to apply the users timezone diff?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, utc

I thought about letting my users having to select their own timezone in my application, but what about instead making it automatic with some javascript?

Some psuedocode:
A date is printed serverside as `<p class="utcDate">2011-09-28 11:00 UTC</p>`. When the user loads the page, jquery walks through all elements with the `utcDate` class and replaces the UTC date/time with a date where the diff between UTC & the users local timezone has been applied.

What should I be aware of when doing this? Are there any obvious drawbacks to this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use .getTimezoneOffset() simply? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend outputting the Unix timestamp instead.  The [js Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) doesn't have the capabilities to consume a UTC string directly (you'd have to parse out each component), but it can consume a timestamp using the [setTime](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_settime.asp) function.

The Date object automatically localizes to the user's settings and can be cast to a string directly (although that's probably more verbose than you'd like: "Wed Sep 28 2011 07:03:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"), so you'll likely want to format the string yourself:

```
$('p.utcDate').each(function () {
    var time = new Date();
    time.setTime(this.innerHTML);
    this.innerHTML = time.toDateString();
  });
```

As an added benefit, toDateString will handle local conventions around m-d-y vs d-m-y, etc.

Comment: Why _"The js Date object doesn't have the capabilities to consume a UTC string directly"_? `new Date('2011-09-28 11:00 UTC')` return correct date object in browsers (except IE8 and older).

Comment: I suppose if you don't need to support IE7/8 then yes, you can use the constructor you referenced, but for my work, I'm required to support browsers currently in heavy use.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this (which there is nothing wrong with) be aware that it can affect perceived page-load time if there is a lot of elements involved.

Be sure to do the replacement in a DOM-ready event handler and not on page load, since this would be very visible to the users.

Alternativly instead of outputting the UTC date and then changing it, why not just output a js.snippet that will write the correct date inline via document.write? - This will be faster for pageload.

If it's the same date/time everywhere you use it on a page, you can just generate it once via js, and then simply output the value stored in a variable.